# mysqldbimport csv error invalid table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to do a simple import into a MySQL database. I want to import from a .csv file and create the file with fields based on row 1. I can login, the server says I can import header info - but I can't see it, and I get an error on importing the entire file.

Login to mysql server is successful:

```
    Captains-iMac-4:~ myname$ mysql -p
    Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.6.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle .......

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

    mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mydb               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Attempt to import csv file is unsuccessful: (password x'd out)

```
    Captains-iMac-4:~ myname$ mysqldbimport --server=john_grauel:xxxxxxxx@localhost --            import=both --bulk-insert --format=raw_csv ~/downloads/NCESData/hd2012.csv --table=test,csvimporttest --drop-first
    Usage: mysqldbimport --server=user:pass@host:port:socket db1.csv db2.sql db3.grid

mysqldbimport: error: Invalid table name: test,csvimporttest.
```

Attempting to import just the field headers - This SAYS it completed by I can find no trace of a new file: (password x'd out)

```
    Captains-iMac-4:~ myname$ mysqldbimport --server=john_grauel:xxxxxxxx@localhost --    import=definitions --format=csv ~/downloads/NCESData/hd2012definitions.csv
# Source on localhost: ... connected.
# Importing definitions from /Users/myname/downloads/NCESData/hd2012definitions.csv.
#...done.
Captains-iMac-4:~ myname$
```

I must be missing something really basic here. Any guidance would be appreciated. Also, I have read dozens of pages of MySQL Workbench looking for a way to do this import through the GUI and have found nothing. I find it hard to believe that one is not able to import .csv files through the GUI (creating the fields at the same time).

This is an example version of the type of file I want to import:

UNITID,INSTNM,ADDR,CITY,STABBR,ZIP,FIPS,OBEREG,CHFNM,CHFTITLE,GENTELE,EIN,OPEID,OPEFLAG,WEBADDR
100636,Community College of the Air Force,100 S Turner Blvd,Montgomery,AL,36114-3011,1,0,Jonathan T. Hamill,Commandant,3346495000,-1,1230800,3, 
100654,Alabama A & M University,4900 Meridian Street,Normal,AL,35762,1,5,"Dr. Andrew Hugine, Jr.",President,2563725000,636001109,100200,1,www.aamu.edu/
100663,University of Alabama at Birmingham,Administration Bldg Suite 1070,Birmingham,AL,35294-0110,1,5,Ray L. Watts,President,2059344011,636005396,105200,1,www.uab.edu
100690,Amridge University,1200 Taylor Rd,Montgomery,AL,36117-3553,1,5,Michael Turner,President,3.34388E+13,237034324,2503400,1,www.amridgeuniversity.edu
100706,University of Alabama in Huntsville,301 Sparkman Dr,Huntsville,AL,35899,1,5,Robert A. Altenkirch,President,2568246120,630520830,105500,1,www.uah.edu

And the headers only:

UNITID,INSTNM,ADDR,CITY,STABBR,ZIP,FIPS,OBEREG,CHFNM,CHFTITLE,GENTELE,EIN,OPEID,OPEFLAG,WEBADDR

Comment: Are you able to edit your post with an example of your CSV? I'm unable to replicate the issue based on what you've posted.

Comment: I did so, thanks. The ID is int, the next 5 are text the last is int. (I mistakenly said the first field was text in my comment to the edit).

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV data, in fact there isn't a delimiter at all. Did you copy that out of something like excel? To help debug your issue we need the raw csv (open it in notepad or another text editor). Both files too, definitions and the data one.

Comment: I corrected the import file listings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty amazing - and a bit hard to believe. The .csv file that I originally used came from a file saved with Excel on a MAC as a .csv file. I reopened that .csv file (still on the MAC) and saved it as Microsoft .csv file and the import into MySQL Workbench works. Note that using the option to save as MS-DOS .csv does not work.